# Basic string formatting in XML or JSON for mobile apps

Tags: html, xml, json, string-formatting

What is the most appropriate method to communicate basic text formatting, such as line breaks, from a RESTful style service serving XML or JSON? The content will be rendered as native text on iOS and Android (i.e. not a Webview).

For **XML** I can see three options:

**Option #1**: Use of CDATA tags and HTML and then parse the HTML, for example:

```
<element>
    <![CDATA[
    This is the text that requires basic formatting. <br />
    Maybe it also requires a paragraph: <p>Hello World!</p>
    ]]>
</element>
```

**Option #2**: Remove CDATA and allow formatting tags to be part of the XML file and then parse the HTML:

```
<element>
    This is the text that requires basic formatting. 
    <br />
    Maybe it also requires a paragraph: 
    <p>
        Hello World!
    </p>
</element>
```

**Option #3**: Use some custom syntax that is parsed by the app and replaced with appropriate native formatting.

For **JSON** I can see two options:

**Option #1**: Inlcude HTML in JSON:

```
{
    "content": "This is the text that requires basic formatting. <br />
    Maybe it also requires a paragraph: <p>Hello World!</p>"    
}
```

**Option #2**: Use some custom syntax that is parsed by the app and replaced with appropriate native formatting (same as XML **Option#3**).

Perhaps using a WebView and rendering HTML directly *is* the most appropriate method if these solutions are tending towards being 'hacky'.